# Can MVC be used for Windows applications?

Tags: mvc

When I attended an interview, the interviewer asked me "Is MVC used for Windows Applications?" But I said no.

Is my answer correct or not?

Comment: Cross site dupe: [How would you implement mvc in a windows forms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122388/how-would-you-implement-mvc-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: It depends on wether the interviewer was referring to the MVC concept (yes) or to the MVC.Net class libraries (no). You could have a windows application with a self-hosting web solution (remote control or something) but generally the MVC.Net class library were engineered specifically for web applications. You can use a round table as a bicycle wheel, but those legs will get in the way... The **concept** however is usable. In WPF applications you will find the MVVM variant of the same concept. In general, the majority of statefull (winforms) applications tend to be lax in this regard.

Comment: I removed the meta discussion, as it was getting a bit long. Here's a quick summary of it: _People are not required to comment when downvoting_. Please try to keep any further comments focused on the topic of the question.

Comment: I find it amazing people think it takes too long to leave a "off topic" or "too broad" comment, but they take the time to fix the question so the English is correct.  Also, talk about straw man, I never one mentioned that this should be required.  I think we have all expended more energy that this question or my comments are worth.

Answer (score 4):

It can be.  It doesn't have to be.

MVC is about separating three areas of responsibility.  The model is responsible for state that models the world being represented.  The view is responsible for presenting a way to view that state.  The controller is responsible for allowing manipulations to be made to that state.

This is all MVC really is.  It's very old, one of our first patterns, and people have tried to add to it and have renamed it and twisted it, so studying it can be confusing.

It is entirely possible to not separate these responsibilities and still make a working application.  Separating them helps make the application easier to maintain.  It's also possible to come up with more areas of responsibility to separate into and go beyond MVC.

It's also difficult to nail down how these areas are supposed to communicate with each other.  Back when MVC started they never really explained that.  Consequently, you'll discover the way MVC is actually implemented can vary widely.

As someone who's developed windows applications I can tell you there are cases where you find yourself using it without even knowing because the framework you're using is taking care of that.  That way you can just write monkey see monkey do code for event handlers and such without even thinking about MVC.  You wont notice the separation until you've dug under the covers.  The point of asking you a question like this is to find out if you can dig under the covers.

See also Model–View–Presenter (MVP), Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM), and Hexagonal architecture to name a very few.

Comment: To be honest I don't think the interviewer is expecting this kind of answer :P. He'll probably expect something like "when using WinForm/<another techno> yes it use MVC".

Comment: @Walfrat Giving an interviewer exactly what they expect isn't a good thing.  The objective is to impress, not bore.

Answer (score 3):

MVC is about User Empowerment and Direct Manipulation. It was invented for (the very first) graphical desktops. You can most certainly use it to build Windows applications.

MVC was created at a time when computing was very un-democratic: programs were written by programmers, computers were operated by operators, and programs and computers were used by users, and there was a strict separation between the three. As a result, there was very little connection between how the users thought about a problem and how the problem was represented in code. MVC was invented as a way to rectify both problems: to represent problems the way the *user* thinks about them, and to empower the user to be more than a passive recipient.

The Model is an extension of the user's brain. It represents concepts preferably as close as possible to how they think about them. The job of the View and the Controller is to give the user the illusion that she is directly manipulating the Model with her thoughts (Direct Manipulation Metaphor). Views and Controllers should be written by the users themselves, maybe with assistance from developers (User Empowerment). Therefore, they should be written in a language that is easy for users to understand. (MVC was first thoroughly described and implemented in Smalltalk, which is a language designed to be easily understandable and usable even by children.)

As you can see, there is absolutely nothing in here that would be in any way specific to any particular operating system.